# Spark scala input/output directories

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark

I am new to Spark/Scala Programming.I am able to do the set up using the maven and able to run the sample word count program.

I am having 2 questions over here for both running in spark environment/ in Windows local:
1.How the scala program is identifying the input.
2.How to write the output into text file.

Here is my code

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.rddToPairRDDFunctions
object WordCount {
 def main(args: Array[String]) = {

//Start the Spark context
val conf = new SparkConf()
  .setAppName("WordCount")
  .setMaster("local")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

//Read some example file to a test RDD
val textFile = sc.textFile("file:/home/root1/Avinash/data.txt")

val counts = textFile.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
             .map(word => (word, 1))
             .reduceByKey(_ + _)
             counts.foreach(println)
             counts.collect()
    counts.saveAsTextFile("file:/home/root1/Avinash/output")

}
```

}

When I place the file in file:/home/root1/Avinash/data.txt and try to run it didnt work.Only when i place the data.txt in /home/root1/softs/spark-1.6.1/bin or inside the project folder in workspace it is trying to take the input.

Similarly, when I am trying to write into output using     counts.saveAsTextFile("file:/home/root1/Avinash/output"), it is not writing and instead it is throwing the error as 
                                                                              Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: D.

Please help me in resolving this!!.

Answer (score 3):

you suppose to use /// on file. this is an example

```
val textFile = sc.textFile("file:///home/root1/Avinash/data.txt")

val counts = textFile.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
             .map(word => (word, 1))
             .reduceByKey(_ + _).cache() 

             counts.foreach(println)
             //counts.collect()
    counts.saveAsTextFile("file:///home/root1/Avinash/output")
```

use cache to avoid compute every time you are doing action on RDD if the file is big